# Join 3 tables in SQL Server and add new columns with their respective data

Tags: sql-server, excel, join

I have three tables 
 1. **dbo.Loan** with with columns *LoanId, LoanNum*. 
 2. **dbo.LoanBor** with columns *LoanId, BorRefNum* where all rows in *BorRefNum* = 1. 
 3. **npi.LoanBor** with columns *LoanId, BorRefNum, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, SSN*.

I have 80 rows in **npi.LoanBor** and these all are borrower’s data.

I have an excel sheet with 40 rows which has co-borrower’s data. It has co-borrower’s *FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, SSN, LoanNum*.

I want to update **dbo.LoanBor**’s *BorRefNum* = 2, if, the LoanNum of co-borrower in the excel sheet = LoanNum of Borrower in the **npi.LoanBor**.

Also, I want to add four columns: *Co-Borrower Name (First, M Initial, Last)* and *Co-BorrowerSSN* with their respective data in **npi.LoanBor** table where the LoanNum of co-borrower in the excel sheet = LoanNum of Borrower in the **npi.LoanBor**

Comment: What part are you having an issue with? Can you post your code which is causing the error, and the error you are getting? As it stands, your question is too broad, and would be better directed at a paid consultant. This post should help: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql

Comment: Do you want to add the four columns to dbo.LoanBoar?  Then that's just an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN command.

Comment: @scsimon as much as like Gianluca (aka spaghettia dba) that may be my new favorite link for such directions. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Import your excel sheet to SQL Server (e.g. using SSMS/task/import data)
2. write an `UPDATE` statement using a join between the data loaded from excel and your current dbo.LoanBor table.
3. `ALTER TABLE dbo.LoanBor` to add the four new colums
4. `UPDATE dbo.LoanBor` from npi.LoanBor and the data loaded from Excel